# FreeRTOS with ATMega328P

Tags: atmega328p, rtos, freertos

Im trying to run FreeRTOS on ATMega328P and with two tasks its works well, but when i put one more  task, no one is scheduling, I got the return of CreateTask of all tasks created and is right, all of it returned pdPASS, so all was created, and the vTaskScheduler() is executing, but if i try to print something from within of the task no one show something, so no one is in the ReadyState i think, the idle Hook function also dont execute.

Comment: How large did you configure your heap size? How much stack do you allocate per task? How much RAM does your poor ATMega have? Are you sure this is the processor of choice if you're running a relatively rich RTOS like FreeRTOS?

Comment: Are you able to run any two out of three?  ie. Does the 3rd task run by itself?  If so, then @MarcusMüller has your clues/guidance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample code that reproduces the problem. Without any  more information to go on, all we can do is guess about what the problem might be. As a side benefit, it may turn out that creating such a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will allow you to discover the root cause of the problem yourself, in which case you can answer your own question.

Comment: Try allocating the tasks statically.